# $(this).parent().siblings('.classname').show() does not work

Tags: jquery

HTML :

```
<div class="quiz-template">
    <span class="question">1. What is the first word in the first chapter of the series?</span>

    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img2/q1.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="answer-container">
        <div class="a-choice1">
            <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="0" />
            <label for="btn1"></label>
            <span>The</span>

        </div>

        <div class="a-choice1">
            <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="0" />
            <label for="btn2"></label>
            <span>Albus</span>
        </div>

        <div class="a-choice1">
            <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="0" />
            <label for="btn3"></label>
            <span>Number</span>
        </div>

        <div class="a-choice1">
            <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="1" />
            <label for="btn4"></label>
            <span>Mr.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result-container" id="r1">
        <!--
        <span class="tic mark">✓</span> 
        <span class="cross mark">X</span>
        -->
        <span class="result-text"></span>
        <span class="result-description">
            The first sentence reads, “Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much.”
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show the results-container class hidden by display:none; through the function

```
$('.a-choice1').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.results-container').show("fast"); 
});
```

but it doesn't work. What is wrong with my traversing code? Also, is there a way that I can make the value inside the selector dynamic so I could do a loop? Sort of like:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('div[id=r '+N+']').show("fast");
```

where N is an integer that could increment in value to access ids r1, r2, r3... and so on?

Comment: Why are you using `$(this)`?

Comment: The javascript code is encased in a "$('.a-choice1').click(function () {});" i'm sorry

Comment: Why dont you ashow your code on jsfiddle so we can fiddle it

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9UEQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.a-choice1').find("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".answer-container").next(".result-container").show("fast");
});
```

`parents()` (with a selector) : http://api.jquery.com/parents/

`next()` (with a selector) : http://api.jquery.com/next/

Here's a jsfiddle for ya:

http://jsfiddle.net/rePgM/

To do a loop, it would look like this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.result-container').each(function(e, i){
     $(this).show("fast");  //$(this) now refers to each instance of the parent's siblings
});
```

This eliminates your need to send an ID number as well.

Comment: It isn't working. I've created a fiddle of my code trying to apply your code: http://jsfiddle.net/r9UEQ/

Comment: Change your click to what I have above.  I changed it to listen for a click on the radiobutton, rather than the div.  Those divs may not be large enough to click (might be 1px high).  `$('.a-choice1').find("input[type=radio]")`

Comment: Also, you're missing a dot in the parents selector!

Comment: Darn, just saw it too just now! Hahaha I'm sorry! Your code works.

Comment: I forked your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rePgM/

Always remember to set jQuery in the drop down box on the far left, too!

Comment: Your selector was all screwy, too, near the bottom.  Can't remember exactly what it said, but it was wrong.

Comment: Was it the "$(this).siblings().find("input").trigger("click");"?

Comment: No, this:  `$(this).parent().find(div[class="answer-container"]).show("fast");`  The find() selector should have quotes around it.  However, selectors for classes should just be shortened to `find(".answer-container")` using a dot `.` instead of `[class='`

Answer (score 0):

try find method

```
$(this).parent().find('div#r'+N).show("fast");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Is the syntax of the value inside the find selector correct? Because I'm not aware that you can do that. I thought it was supposed to go: div[name/id='.className/#idName'];

Comment: you certainly can do div#idname or div.classname. Think of jquery selectors as css selectors, the majority of them get sent directly to `document.querySelectorAll()`. Note however that you should never do tagname#idname, as #idname will be MANY times faster.

Comment: I've heard the `div.classname` selector is faster than `.selector`, though, because it will only parse the divs in the DOM, rather than *every element*.  But, having `div#idname` would be slower because then it will look at *every* div, instead of just the one. (Which is another reason why you never use the same id more than once)

Comment: not you can not find difference between div#someID and #someID